# How to access the file shared between different accessors?

Tags: java, python, concurrency

I have code written on Java which writes all data to the file and then I have python script which handles this data.

They run completely separately and python script can be run by schedule but it also removing handled records from the file.
The question is in implementation for the access to the file when java code from first process will try to write something and python code from second process will try to remove handled record?

First thought was to have .lock file physically created when one of the processes updating the file but perhaps there are some other solutions to consider?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be to ditch the use of a file and use sockets.  The Java program generates and caches the output until a Python script is listening.  The Python script then accepts the data, and handles it.

Alternatively, you could use IPC signalling between the two processes, although this seems a lot more messy than sockets, IMHO.

Otherwise, a .lock file seems like your best bet.

Comment: Messaging might be more robust in this case than sockets.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Thats certainly true, and would allow you to inform the other process that an error has occurred.  Nice point.

Answer (score 0):

One mechanism would be to have the producer roll the file to a new name (maybe with `HHMMSS` suffix) every so often, and have the consumer only process the file once it has been rolled to the new name.  Maybe every 5 minutes?

Another mechanism would be to have the consumer roll the file itself and have the producer notice that the file has rolled and to re-open the original file name.  So the consumer is always consuming from `output.consume` and the producer is always writing to `output` or something.

- Every time a line is written to the file, the producer makes sure that `output` exists.
- When a consumer is ready to read the file, he renames `output` to `output.consume` or something.
- The producer notices that the file `output` no longer exists so he reopens it for output.
- Once the `output` file is re-created the consumer can process the `output.comsume` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both the Java and Python methods close the file when they are done.

One possibility is to convert your Python script to Jython. If both processes are running in the JVM then you should be able to use standard Java concurrency techniques to make sure you do not have both threads modifying the file simultaneously.